# make dataframe condition wise

Tags: python, pandas

we have to Entered or choose any DPD value

i have df like this:

```
  NPA Status    MSME Classifcation (Sub segment)    Contact Number  Scheme Type
0    N                 MICRO                             nan           CCA
1    N                 MICRO                          6359434643.0     LAA
2    N                 MICRO                          6359434643.0     ODA
3    N                 MICRO                          6359434643.0     LAA
```

1. if DPD  Null than its consider as a Invalid
2. if NPA Status == Y then it's invalid
3. Scheme Type - CCA, ODA, LAA then it's valid
4. if  MSME Classifcation (Sub segment) is in 'MICRO or 'small' then valid
5. if Contact Number blank or NUll it's invalid

i try with

```
def f(x,DPD):
    
    if DPD >=1 and x['NPA Status'] in ['N'] and x['Scheme Type'] in (['CCA','ODA','LAA'])\
            and x['MSME Classifcation (Sub segment)'] in (['MICRO','SMALL'])\
            and re.search(r'^([0]|\+91)?[6789]\d{9}$',x['Contact Number']):
        return ("pass")
    else:
        return ("Fail")

df['Invalid'] = t.apply(f,args = (10), axis=1)
```

I want this using isin function instead of in

```
      NPA Status    MSME Classifcation (Sub segment)    Contact Number  Scheme Type  Invalid
    0    N                 MICRO                             nan           CCA         True
    1    Y                 MICRO                          6359434643.0     LAA         True
    2    N                 MICRO                          6359434643.0     ODA         False
    3    N                 MICRO                          6359434643.0     LAA         False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using several boolean indexes together:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NPA Status': ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'N'],
    'MSME Classifcation (Sub segment)': ['MICRO', 'MICRO', 'MICRO', 'MICRO'],
    'Contact Number': ['', '6359434643', '6359434643', '6359434643'],
    'Scheme Type': ['CCA', 'LAA', 'ODA', 'LAA']
})

DPD = 10

# Create Conditions For Valid
c1 = df['NPA Status'].eq('N')
c2 = df['Scheme Type'].isin(['CCA', 'ODA', 'LAA'])
c3 = df['MSME Classifcation (Sub segment)'].isin(['MICRO', 'SMALL'])
c4 = df['Contact Number'].str.match('^([0]|\+91)?[6789]\d{9}$')

# Use boolean logic to evaluate (short circuit based on if DPD is null or not)
df['Invalid'] = ~(c1 & c2 & c3 & c4) if DPD else False

# For Display
print(df.to_string())
```

Or with a function:

```
def fn(frame, DPD=None):
    if not DPD:  # Short Cut based on DPD
        return False
    c1 = frame['NPA Status'].eq('N')
    c2 = frame['Scheme Type'].isin(['CCA', 'ODA', 'LAA'])
    c3 = frame['MSME Classifcation (Sub segment)'].isin(['MICRO', 'SMALL'])
    c4 = frame['Contact Number'].str.match('^([0]|\+91)?[6789]\d{9}$')

    return ~(c1 & c2 & c3 & c4)


df['Invalid'] = fn(df, DPD=10)
```

```
  NPA Status MSME Classifcation (Sub segment) Contact Number Scheme Type  Invalid
0          N                            MICRO                        CCA     True
1          Y                            MICRO     6359434643         LAA     True
2          N                            MICRO     6359434643         ODA    False
3          N                            MICRO     6359434643         LAA    False
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
 in second solution

Comment: Use contains instead of match

Comment: Yeah. I changed the type of your contact number column from float to string. Because that pattern was never going to work on `6,359,434,643.0`. I should have clarified.

Comment: And condition Not work , it's showing All True